# Gravity Forms - Sending custom data through notification email

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Is there any kind of hooks available through which we can send the survey data with some custom calculation in email? If not, what is the best way to do it?

We have a survey & at the end it generates a score based on some custom calculation. Now in the notification email, we get the survey results data, but want to send the results as well.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hidden field in the same form and store your result based on the custom calculation in that field and then you can use that field in Email Notifications.

Below are the GF third-party plugins which were useful for custom calculations for me. You can find a few more too. Also, refer their Support forum for useful articles.

https://legacy.forums.gravityhelp.com/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gf-minmax-calculation/

This is the easiest method for your kind of requirement.
If you want to go by hooks, you can use the below hooks for changing the email notification content.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_send_email/

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_notification/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can use hidden field, but results are dynamic. It will generate based on user inputted value into the survey. Any idea how do I store that value into hidden field?

Comment: Yes. Create an input type NUMBER field and make it hidden. You can use the CALCULATIONS option in GF to have change dynamically based on user inputs.
Refer to this URL: https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-calculations/
Upvote and accept the answer if this helps.

Comment: Do upvote the answer so it would be useful for others too.

Comment: Had already Upvoted but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."